# jquery slider to change body background

Tags: jquery, css, cookies, background

I want to include a mini menu 20px by 20px images of potential backgrounds.
When a user clicks on one them the body background image will change and the selection saved as the users choice.

I've thought of using a slider but I don't know how I would be able to have the images in a `li` and be able to change the body css based on the selection.

Any ideas?

Happy July 4th

EDIT
i am trying to save the img url in that cookie, its not working tho, its saving in the cookie but its not retrieving the cookie content

EDIT
the below works, !!!!!!! but the background color is always white even if i add 
a  `$("html").css("background-color","red");`

FIX, added color at the end of the url

```
$("html").css("background", "url('" + imgCookieLink + "') no-repeat fixed center top #343837"); 


$(document).ready(function() {
$("#BGSelector a").click(function() {
    var imgLink = $("img", this).attr("src");
    $.cookie("html_img", "" + imgLink + "", { expires: 7 });
    var imgCookieLink = $.cookie("html_img");
    $("html").css("background", "url('" + imgCookieLink + "')");
});
});

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#BGSelector a").click(function() {
       var imgLink = $("img", this).attr("src");
       $.cookie("html_img", "" + imgLink + "", { path: '/vitamovie', expires: 7 });
       var imgCookieLink = $.cookie("html_img");       
       $("html").css("background", "url('" + imgCookieLink + "') no-repeat fixed center    top"); 
    }); 
 });

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {   
       var imgCookieLink = $.cookie("html_img");  
       $("html").css("background", "url('" + imgCookieLink + "') no-repeat fixed center top");

 });

</script>
```

Comment: thanks tvanfosson for the editing :D

Comment: I am not sure why background-color won't change. But I strongly recommend you try $("body").css("background-color", "#FF0000") and see what happens.

Comment: $("body").css("background-color", "#FF0000");
works fine,

Comment: i have another problem, locally this all works but on on the web its not working
the the cookies are changing but the body is not changing 
http://vitamovie.com

Comment: fixed it, the cookie path was wrong :)

Comment: This is old but... Just found a great plugin that seems to have matured quite a bit. Check out [Supersized](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/), it seems to be exactly what you (and I) need, and something like this saves me a great deal of time rolling by own.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No idea why you use slider in terms of "choosing" something that is discrete. Generally a slider is for some continous changing values like selecting RGB value (which each channel starts from 0 - 255). For your mini-menu thing, which is very simple JQ + CSS:

HTML Markup for the menu

```
<ul id="BGSelector">
    <li><a href="#ChangeBG"><img src="bgImageSource1"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="#ChangeBG"><img src="bgImageSource2"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="#ChangeBG"><img src="bgImageSource3"/></a></li>
</ul>
```

And the Magic JQ statements

```
// Init the bg change UI (which is within document ready)
$(function(){
    $("#BGSelector a").click(function() {
        var imgLink = $("img", this).attr("src");

        // change the body background css
        $("body").css("background", "url('" + imgLink + "')");
    });
});
```

Comment: For saving user preference, take a look at the JQuery.cookie plugin. You just have to save the url into the cookie and retrieve every time document loads

Comment: thanks will try right now, 
yeah when i said slider i meant like a ul, li slider/gallery,

Comment: i am saving it, but i am retrieving it incorrectly, can you please help

Comment: are you sure your retrieved value is wrong? I mean you may try to alert(imgCookieLink) and see what is the value within. It seems like what you do $("html").css should not be working, since an html document cannot have background (even don't have style), only the "body" tag and tags in between can have. try $("body").css instead.

Comment: Official answer from w3, XHTML xsd. Attribute group for tag "html" contains no definition for css. And it is really reasonable for definition on html, it is just the container tag that holds the "head" and "body". Which, head is just for something "no-visible" like metadata and stylesheet link and javascript. And body is the actual "body" of the document which is for display purpose. Eventhough "html" can set background and some browser allow it and display, it is not the good practice and it actually violates the definition and the html is simply cannot be validated.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I don't know if this can be useful but, what i did was

```
var url= data.bgimg[0] ;
$('body').css('background-image',"url(" + url + ")");
```

where url is (obviously) the path to the img. I got it via json but you can change it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var newBg = ['headercaption.gif', 'loading.gif', 'excelexport.gif', 'grid-layer.gif'];
var path="themes/default/images/";
var i = 0;
var rotateBg = setInterval(function(){
    $('body').css('backgroundImage' ,  "url('" +path+newBg[i]+ "')");
    if(i==4)
     i=0;
     else
      i++;
}, 5000);
```